# How to write one single update query(to update 1 column) in JDBC by using a reusable code for different columns?

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g

I want to update :
1.Name
2.Salary
3.Number
in JDBC. 
So, I wrote a whole big code to update user values in jdbc with
`PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("update tablename set name=? where id=?")`; 
Then as usual we use methods like ps.setString() and ps.setInt(); followed by ps.executeQuery()
This works fine. But now I have to rewrite the same lines of code to update salary and number. My question is, Is there any way that I can use same code for this thing? 
I tried:

```
String name="name";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("update tablename set ?=? where id=?");
ps.setString(name);
```

and variations like these. 
But it does not work. In my project, I have many such fields, if I write different update codes for every seperate field, its going to increase the lines in my java files a lot. I want optimisation.
Any thoughts on this ? Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to *bind a column name*.

But this does not mean that you need an extra code for each column.

You can  dynamically create the SQL string

```
"update tablename set " + getColumnname() + " =? where id=?"
```

and you must implement a different code path for each *data type* of the updated column, e.g. `setString`, `setLong`, ...

*If you get the column name as an external parameter, you should check it if this is realy a column name to prevent SQL injection*.